# How do I 'UNSTABLE' a Jenkins pipeline build if Pester test fails?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, pester

I have the following Jenkinsfile to run a Powershell Pester Test.  How do I get the build result of 'UNSTABLE' if the pester tests do NOT pass?

```
                stage('Version, Build and Test Updated Roles') {
                when {
                    allOf {
                        branch 'feature/ABC'
                        expression { currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS' }
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    powershell script: '''
                    try
                    {
                        $env:BRANCH_NAME
                        Invoke-Build -Task Version, BuildUpdatedRoles -VSTS -ErrorAction Stop
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Write-Output $PSItem
                        exit $LastExitCode
                    }
                    '''
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set build result with `currentBuild.result`

```
                stage('Version, Build and Test Updated Roles') {
                when {
                    allOf {
                        branch 'feature/ABC'
                        expression { currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS' }
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    script {
                        try {
                            powershell script: '''
                    try
                    {
                        $env:BRANCH_NAME
                        Invoke-Build -Task Version, BuildUpdatedRoles -VSTS -ErrorAction Stop
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Write-Output $PSItem
                        exit $LastExitCode
                    }
                    '''
                        } catch (err) {
                            currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for input.  I just found out that the PS script required some changes in order for the build to fail (or unstable) if pester test failed.  See new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
                stage('Version, Build and Test Updated Roles') {
                when {
                    allOf {
                        branch 'feature/ABC'
                        expression { currentBuild.currentResult == 'SUCCESS' }
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    script {
                        powershell script: '''
                            try
                            {
                                $env:BRANCH_NAME
                                Invoke-Build -Task Version, BuildUpdatedRoles -VSTS -ErrorAction Stop
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                Write-Output $PSItem
                                exit 1
                            }
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
```